# How can I change default location for tablespaces

Tags: oracle

In Oracle, how can I find out where datafiles for a tablespace are created by default if I do not provide a full path for the datafile but just the name?
And how can I change this default location?

Answer (score 1):

`show parameter db_create_file_dest` will point to default datafile location.

To change default location execute this command

`alter system set db_create_file_dest='target_dir' scope=both;`

(change is immediate no need to bounce the database)